# JQuery Draggable Sortable bug need workaround for display:none;

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I seem to have found a bug in jQuery UI that duplicates dragged elements when one of the target sortables is hidden. I managed to duplicate it in a very simple jsfiddle. I am in a time crunch so I can't really wait for a patch.

Here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BpfGC/1/
To duplicate the bug drag a letter form the green box up to the red box then toggle the contents of the blue box. you will see a duplicate of whichever letter you dragged up to red. This is in Firefox and Chrome.

Can anyone figure out a workaround or why this is happening?

Comment: I guess I should have fiddled a little longer. I found a workaround. All you have to do is hide the container of the sortable you are using as a target instead of the sortable itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a bug when using helper: "clone" with a hidden sortable. I answered my own question above and when you hide the container it works fine. That seems like a bug to me.

so: 
`<ul class="sortable" style="display:none;"></ul>` 
will reproduce the bug but 
`<div style="display:none;"><ul class="sortable"></ul></div>`
 works as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't always an ideal solution.